# Android: Using Intents to Open a URL without "http"

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using an intent to open up a specific string literal(the website address) in an Android device's browser.

If I go with

```
String myIntentString = "url:www.google.com"
Uri myInputUri = Uri.parse(myIntentString);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myInputUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then the app crashes.

However, if I change my string to "http://www.google.com" (the correct format), then it obviously works.

Yes, this is a school assignment and it is specified that the string MUST be "url:www.google.com"

If it helps, this is the first assignment where we need to turn in the Android Manifest file. Does this mean it has to do with that?
What am I missing?

Comment: Only the input string must be `url:www.google.com`? Just `myIntentString = myIntentString.replace("url:", "http://");`.

Comment: Thank you, I've wondered about that, but given the context of the assignment not being on string manipulation

Basically, I want to make sure there isn't some way involving intents that I'm overlooking